# Micrometer traceId is lost when switching threads in Kotlin's coroutines

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, micrometer

In a simple kotlin Spring Boot 3 application, with Micrometer Tracing, I was expecting the trace context to propagate between threads. However that seems not to be the case.

In this simple RestController we can verify that the traceId is lost after calling the kotlin **delay** method. In the second **log** statement, we are on a different Thread and the **traceId** is **null**.

```kotlin
import io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class TestController(
    val tracer: Tracer
) {

    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    @GetMapping("/test")
    suspend fun test() {
        logger.info("before: ${tracer.currentTraceContext().context()?.traceId()}")
        delay(50)
        logger.info("after:  ${tracer.currentTraceContext().context()?.traceId()}")
    }
}
```

I thought the Micrometer library would propagate the trace context when the thread changes. Please note that I'm including the **context-propagation** library.

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("io.micrometer:context-propagation:1.0.2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The coroutine was yield to dispatcher at `delay(50)`, and would be rescheduled (maybe on another thread) after `50`. The dispatcher won't propagate the traceContext properly.

I'm still looking for solutions.

Comment: I understand that, but I was expecting that the Micrometer library would contain hooks that propagate the coroutine contexts during a Thread switch. It seems to me that, if this is not the case, the Micrometer Tracing is useless with Kotlin

Comment: there is a bug reported https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/issues/174 - I think we should wait for the solutions... meanwhile I had to invoke manualy ContextSnapshot.setThreadLocalsFrom (see the article for more info 
https://betterprogramming.pub/tracing-in-spring-boot-3-webflux-d432d0c78d3e)

Comment: @Lama even ContextSnapshot.setThreadLocalsFrom is not working for me with spring WebClient and coroutine - any other workarounds?